# Ubuntu 18.04 using VPN have Ipv6 leak

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, ipv6

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with all the updates. I am also using a VPN that supports Ipv6. After setting up my VPN some time ago I kept getting stuff from Thailand where I live. I finally found doileak.com. When I run the doileak.com test it told me I have several leaks.  I corrected several issues, but one I have not been able to correct.
IPv6 Request Source:

```
Your IPv6 request and IPv4 request are coming from different sources.2403:6200:8851:d7f9:7806:8845:5358:a895 Jasmine International Tower (), Thailand (AS)

Your IPv6 request seem not to go through the same route as your IPv4. If you are using a proxy or VPN, make sure it supports IPv6 or you are easily identified.
```

Doing a lookup query I get:

```
mlempenau@mlempenau18:~$ nslookup www.google.com
Server: 127.0.0.53
Address: 127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: www.google.com
Address: 172.217.11.36
Name: www.google.com
Address: 2607:f8b0:4006:815::2004
```

This tells me I have Ipv6 and for that matter Ipv4 correctly set up (I think!) so people think I'm in the US. Yet when I run doileak.com it gets something different. I'm not sure what to do next to determine where my leak is. Any help would be appreciated.

One more observation. I use Windows 10 from time to time. I set windows up with the VPN and changed all the DNS settings. It works just fine and without the above problem.